# Can browsing history be remotely manipulated

Tags: history, browsing, google-hangouts

Is it possible to remotely manipulate browsing history on a personal laptop?  For example, if someone's browsing history showed they were looking up ways to poison their spouse, is it possible that someone outside the home or network could be trying to set them up?

Another similar question - If someone's browsing history showed they were chatting on Google Hangouts with someone on their contact list, is it possible that an anonymous person could be responsible for doing it instead?  And if Open DNS were set up and showed specific traffic to a site, could that traffic be generated by anyone outside the home?  These questions probably sound a little bizarre but I have a good reason for asking and I would honestly appreciate any help I can get.  The laptop in question is an Acer running Windows 7.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Anything is possible if your computer has been hacked.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way for an "attacker" to do something like this would be to install remote access software on the laptop. (A quick search for "remote access software" will show many options.) The laptop could then be controlled remotely as if someone were sitting at the keyboard. Generally, an attacker would have to have physical access to the laptop to do the initial software install, or else trick the laptop user into installing it (and it wouldn't necessarily be obvious to the user that they're installing remote access software). Typically, the attacker would have to use the laptop while the owner is away, or otherwise not paying attention, since their activity would look like the computer is controlling itself, which would obviously look suspicious.

Technically sophisticated attackers would have additional methods for achieving remote access, and their activity would not necessarily be obviously visible to the user.

Comment: If the browsing history matches the times the user is online, the sites visited are ones the user has a history of hitting and, strangely, no attempt to use the opportunity for financial gain, is there any way to prove the history does indeed belong to the user?

Comment: Thank you so much for responding to my questions.  I know it must seem pretty trivial but I can promise you that it isn't to me.  I use this forum as a last resort, after I have exhausted my searches online.  Your generosity is very much appreciated.

Comment: Obviously I'm missing a lot of context here, and I'm not entirely clear on what you mean by the "opportunity", but in general, it's hard to definitively prove anything in the presence of a skilled/sophisticated attacker who knows how to cover their tracks and/or create misleading "evidence". If you are confident there's no such attacker involved, then maybe the evidence will speak for itself. On the other hand, sometimes the truth is stranger than you can imagine. Sorry I can't be of more help.